# Use forwardRef to avoid importing a module

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, components

I've got three modules (`Module1`, `Module2`, `ModalModule`). Both modules need to import `ModalModule`, but the problem is that `ModalModule` needs to import `Module1` as well because of `Component1`. Of course this creates a circular dependency.
My question is, how could I use `forwardRef` to somehow resolve this circular dependency? My best bet would be to remove the `Module1` import of `ModalModule` (red arrow) and somehow inject `Component1` using `ForwardRef` (because all the modules that use `ModalModule` have `Component1`).

[image: Sketch of the modules]

Comment: The easiest solution is to create a shared module that declares and exports the component1. This way you can import component1 into `Module1` and `ModalModule`, and you don't need to import `Module1` into `ModalModule` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a component called ng-content that allows you to insert external components as the content of your component. With this approach, you can delete Module1 as a dependency of ModalModule.

For example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2> Modal content </h2>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <modal>
        <div>This element will be injected to ng-content</div>
      </modal>
    </div>
  `
})
```

In the case of MatDialog:

Module1Component

```
<ng-template #template>
  <div>Some content</div>
</ng-template>
...

@ViewChild("template")
template: TemplateRef<any>;
...

constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}
...

this.dialog.open<DialogComponent, DialogData>(DialogComponent, {
  template: this.template
} as DialogData)
...
```

ModalModuleComponent

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="data.template"></ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: My only problem is that the ModalComponent is not used in the template, instead it is programmatically created in both modules.

Comment: You can provide content on this way:
https://www.codegram.com/blog/playing-with-dialogs-and-ng-templates/